# Open Gmail with Cordova startapp

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I want to open Gmail app from my ionic app and show the inbox.

I'm using `cordova plugin startapp`
https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp

```
var sApp = startApp.set({
    "application":"com.google.android.gm"
}).start();
```

This works perfectly but the problem is it shows last open activity of gmail app,
I want to show the inbox

Comment: Android or iOS? or both?

Comment: Both Android and Ios